# ROS Answers SE migration: RPLIDAR RVIZ

Tags: ros, rviz, rplidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys!

My question is quite simple, i have been searching for 2 days and i couldn't find the answer.

I'm building my own robot, using RPi3 with a RPLidar and SLAM for mapping. How can I see the position of the robot (I can see the data and the map, but not where my robot is) , or at least the frame in the RViz output? I tried whit a lot of configs in the RViz control panel and nothing happend.

Here is the launch file I'm using right now.

```
<!--
  Used for visualising rplidar in action.

  It requires rplidar.launch.
 -->
<launch>
  <include file="$(find rplidar_ros)/launch/rplidar.launch" />
  <include file="$(find rplidar_ros)/launch/hectormapping.launch" />
  <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find rplidar_ros)/rviz/slam.rviz" />
</launch>
```

Tyy!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280382/rplidar-rviz/) by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2018-01-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-20**:\

> How can I the position of the robot

You're missing a word there. What are you trying to do? What specifically have you tried? What configurations? Launch files?

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-01-20**:
just trying to see where is my robot in RVIZ.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-20**:
What about the other parts of my previous comment? What specifically have you tried? Launch files? Etc.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-21**:
have you try for Robot model  ?? and if you provide us lunch file we can help You as much as we can

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-01-22**:
that's may be what I'm needing. My launch file is the default view_slam.launch (I will edit my post after this). After reading a little more, I want this. I want to include some model that simulates it's my robot. I don't need something fancy, just a cube it would be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you simply need a way to know where your robot is, and don't really care what it looks like, you can simply add an "Axes" display. Set the reference frame to one of the links of your robot. Something like robot_footprint would work perfectly.
If you want it to look less like 3 lines and more like a single "blob", you can set the length to about 0,1 or 0,2.

---

Originally posted by [JamesDoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/30501/jamesdoe/) with karma: 78 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-01-23**:
This is what I am needing, I will find the way to do it. TY.

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-01-23**:
It works! Thank you!